# Stripe SDK android Give cashback to a user

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe payment gateway.

Want to give cash back to users after shopping some X amount of products.

Not able to find any such option to give user Cash back to bank account or a wallet using Stripe SDK

Is it possible using Stripe SDK?

Answer (score 0):

While you can always offer credit in your own store for future purposes, you can only pay out funds to bank accounts / debit cards via [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) and connected accounts.

You should contact Stripe's [support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) team to describe your business model to help you determine whether you can do this.